# save post data to database in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I Wanna save post data in Laravel. This is my code:

```
public function addContact(Request $request){
    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->addContact($request);
    return back();
}
```

and in the Model:

```
public function addContact($contactData){
       return $this->save($contactData);
}
```

it's saves in the database but the data in it is NOT save. saves like an empty row.
if I change it to this, it's working:

```
public function addContact($contactData){
      $this->user_id = $contactData->user_id;
      $this->text = $contactData->text;
      return $this->save();
}
```

Why the first one is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `create()`

```
return $this->create($contactData);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked Greate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using $fillable on the model?

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'text'];
```

And in Controller

```
public function addContact(Request $request){
    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->create($request);
    return back();
}
```